# If E and H are divergence-free and the time derivative of each other, then why is the Laplacian just the second time derivative?

Tags: vector-analysis, physics

Suppose \begin{alignat*}{2}
&\nabla\cdot E=0\quad\quad\quad&\nabla\cdot H=0 \\
&E=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}&H=-\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}
\end{alignat*}  I need to show that \begin{gather*}
\nabla^2E=\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t^2}\quad\quad\quad\nabla^2H=\frac{\partial^2H}{\partial t^2}
\end{gather*} but I am getting problem even in the signs. Can you help me?

So far, I've noticed that \begin{align*}
\nabla\times(\nabla\times H)&=(\nabla\cdot H)\nabla-\nabla^2H \\
&=-\nabla^2H\quad\quad\quad(\nabla\cdot H=0) \\
\nabla\times\left(-\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}\right)&=−\nabla^2H
\end{align*} but then I don't know how to conclude $$\nabla\times\left(-\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}\right)=\frac{\partial^2E}{\partial t^2}$$  I am not understanding the term $\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$.

Comment: @Shashilina Choudhury: I've retyped your question using MathJax, which makes it easier to read.  Please review it to (1) learn these techniques for yourself and (2) verify that I've correctly transcribed your question.  In particular, your question talked about time derivatives in the body, but $x$-derivatives in the question.  Did you mean for the inconsistency?  (I assumed not.)

Comment: thankyou, and I don't know whether t is time or not. I assumed it is used as a vector or function. I posted it cause I am studying vector differentiation and came across this question in the book. I clearly have no idea how to prove it. So seek for guidance here. Though I would appreciate if the question was in mathematical language other than this but thankyou, I appreciate it.

Comment: I guess the equations for $E$ and $H$ are not entirely correct. Should be $\text{curl} E = -  \frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$, and similar for $E$. Am I correct?

Comment: no it isn't. It is given as curlE= −∂H/∂t.but Maybe the question in the book is wrong but thats whats written.

Comment: I might have expressed myself badly (and make the mistake of writing $B$ instead of $H$). But $\text{curl} E = - \partial H / \partial t$ sounds right. In your post, you wrote a different equation.

Comment: did I? I was sure I wrote it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider two vector fields $E, H \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $E = E(x, t)$ and $H = H(x,t)$. Here $x$ is a spatial variable and $t$ denotes time. Let's assume $E, H \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}; \mathbb{R}^3)$ (this assumption can be weakend, but that's not the point here).

Assume $(E, H)$ solves Maxwell's equations, i.e., for all $(x, t) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}$ there holds
\begin{align}
\nabla_x \cdot E(x, t) &= 0  & \nabla_x \cdot H(x, t) &= 0 \\
\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}(x, t) &= \nabla_x \times H(x,t) & \frac{\partial H}{\partial t} &= - \nabla_x \times E(x,t)
\end{align}
Here $\nabla_x := (\partial_{x_1}, \partial_{x_2}, \partial_{x_3})$.

We need to show that $E = (E_1, E_2, E_3)$ (and $H$) solve the wave equation. By convention, we set
\begin{equation}
\Delta E(x, t) = \nabla^2 E(x, t) := ( \Delta E_1(x, t), \Delta E_2(x, t), \Delta E_3(x, t))\, .
\end{equation}

Applying the curl-operator on $\partial_t H = - \nabla_x \times E$, we find
\begin{equation}
\nabla_x \times \bigg( \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}\bigg) = - \nabla_x \times \Big( \nabla_x \times E\Big) = - \Big( - \Delta E + \nabla_x (\nabla_x \cdot E) \Big)\, . \quad (1)
\end{equation}
As $\nabla_x \cdot E = 0$, interchanging $\nabla_x$ and $\partial_t$ in $(1)$, we get
\begin{equation}
\Delta E = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\big(\nabla_x \times H \big) = \frac{\partial}{ \partial t} \bigg( \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} \bigg) = \frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial t^2}\, .\quad (2)
\end{equation}
Equation $(2)$ is the wave equation, as expected.

The proof for $H$ is similar.